# ModelState.IsValid works on a "new" form, but not on an "edit" form

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-2, entity-framework-4

I have a ASP.NET MVC 2.0 application using Entity Framework.  All my views use view models, most of them complex.  Meaning...the object to be edited is a property of the view model, and not the view model itself.

I am using partial classes with data annotations, and checking ModelState.IsValid inside the POST actions in the controller.

I have a "NEW" form and an "EDIT" form for a simple object with 3 fields!

The ModelState.IsValid check works on the NEW form, and shows the correct "required field" errors, if I try to submit a blank form.

But if I load an EDIT form, and clear the values from some textboxes that are required, and submit the form, I do NOT get validation errors, I just get an exception:

Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper'.

So my question is, does ModelState.IsValid not work with an EDIT form, since perhaps it's looking at the values from the view model object that were loaded, instead of the FormCollection?

```
    // this one does not validate

        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult Edit(int accountStatusKey, AccountStatusEditViewModel model, FormCollection values)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.UpdateAccountStatus(accountStatusKey, values);
                return RedirectToAction("States");
            }
            else
            {
                return View("Edit", model);
            }
        }


    // this one does validate

        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult New(AccountStatusNewViewModel model, FormCollection values)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.AddAccountStatus(values);

                return View("States", new AccountStatusStatesViewModel());
            }
            else
            {
                return View("New", model);
            }
        }

    // how I arrive AT the edit form

        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
        public ActionResult Edit(int accountStatusKey)
        {
            return View("Edit", new AccountStatusEditViewModel(accountStatusKey));
        }

    // and finally, the view model code

    public class AccountStatusEditViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {

        public AccountStatus AccountStatus { get; private set; }

        public IEnumerable States { get; private set; }

        public List StatusTypes { get; private set; }

        public AccountStatusEditViewModel(int accountStatusKey)
        {
            AccountStatus = db.GetAccountStatusByKey(accountStatusKey);
            States = db.GetAllStates();

            StatusTypes = new List();
            StatusTypes.Add("Primary Status");
            StatusTypes.Add("Secondary Status");
            StatusTypes.Add("External Status");
        }

        public AccountStatusEditViewModel()
        {
        }

    }

    // this action method does not work at all either - no db updating, no validation
    // the page simply redirects to "States" view, which should only happen if the db
    // was being updated, right?  But nothing is changing in the DB, and the validation
    // never happens.

        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult Edit(AccountStatusEditViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (TryUpdateModel(model, "AccountStatus"))
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("States");
                }
                else
                {
                    return View("Edit", model);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return View("Edit", model);
            }

        }
```

Comment: Can you post both action methods?

Comment: In your last code example, `public ActionResult Edit(AccountStatusEditViewModel model)` what goes wrong? The model is valid and is correctly updated when it redirect to the states view. Does it also do that when you'd expect the model to contain invalid values?

Comment: Whether the model is valid OR not, I am redirected to the states view, AND nothing is updated in the database.  So Model.IsValid appears to ALWAYS be true, even when the form fields are empty (invalid).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the 2.0 version of MVC i'm not using the formcollection anymore.

I only use the viewmodel in the action's parameter when i have a post, like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Activatecard(ActivateCardViewModel model)
{
```

When 'it' can't create my model (entered blabla for a datetime field, or when the validations are not met (i use the validation attributes from the `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` namespace) i get the `ModelState.IsValid` equals to false.

I created a blank asp.net mvc2 app, and this was the model that the standard template used for the logon action.

Comment: Except that the viewmodel for this page is complex, and the actual object I am trying to update, is a property of the viewmodel, not the viewmodel itself.  I will attach the vide model code now.

Comment: Do you sitll get the exception, when you only add the viewmodel, or does it only just not validate your model?

Answer (score 0):

Please eliminate the FromCollection parameters. You can use the default ModelBinders for your view model. Asp.net MVC try to maps the values from your form into your model.

Can you please post the action method, which leads you to the edit form, too?

Comment: Use the approach from Michel, see post above. This should work for you.

Comment: I changed it to this style, and it still does nothing.  The DB is not updated, and validation is not taking place at all.  I will attach the code abeove.

Comment: How does the view looks like? What model do you use in your view? Can you post the section, where you define your model in the view?